# Why does Android Studio do not accept valid gradle version?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

[image]

I am trying to set the gradle manually, but Android Studio does not allow the version.
I do not want to use gradlew, nor migrate to gradle 6.x

Comment: I think that's because your project has the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin.
Here you can see what version of the Gradle Wrapper you need for your project's gradle plugin version https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Comment: Hello @JorgeE.Hernández, I did downgrade the version and it still did not allow me to click OK.